# Integral closure of the subring $\mathbb Z(A)$ in $A$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Define the image of the ring homomorphism $h:\mathbb Z\to A$ by $\mathbb{Z}(A)$. It is the smallest subring in $A$ with respect to inclusion. I am trying to compute the integral closure of $\mathbb Z(A)$ in $A$, and I guess it should be $\mathbb Z(A)$ itself. Let me recall a familiar example: $\mathbb Z(\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Z$ and the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Z$ itself. Since in general $A$ is not the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z(A)$ anymore, I haven’t figure out how to prove it.

Comment: In the example $A=\mathbb{C}$. Then $i\in\mathbb{C}$ is a root of $x^2+1\in \mathbb{Z}[x]=\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{C})[x]$, but $i\notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I haven’t been looking for counterexamples....thank you for the comment!